# how to loop through each row in datatable and insert data in mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, datarow

I have this code that loops through each row in a datagridview but I don't know what is the equivalent code in using a datatable. I tried using `datarow` instead of `DataGridViewRow` but I don't know how to get the data in each row like I did in this code. So how will I get data in each row in datatable?

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query_1, con))
{
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
if (Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells["quantity"].Value) > 0)
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", dr.Cells["product_name"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variant", dr.Cells["variant_name"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", dr.Cells["size"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@qty", MySqlDbType.Int32, 8).Value = dr.Cells["quantity"].Value;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtboxID.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a syntax like this

```
dr.Field<string>("product_name");
```

Requires a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query_1, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", "");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variant", "");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", 0);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@qty", MySqlDbType.Int32, 8).Value = 0:
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtboxID.Text);
    foreach (DataRow dr in yourTable.Rows)
    {
         if (dr.Field<int>("quantity") > 0)
         {
             cmd.Parameters["@product"].Value = dr.Field<string>("product_name");
             cmd.Parameters["@variant"].Value = dr.Field<string>("variant_name");
             cmd.Parameters["@size".Value = dr.Field<int>("size");
             cmd.Parameters["@qty"].Value = dr.Field<int>("quantity");
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             // no need to clear, reuse the same set of parameters
             //  cmd.Parameters.Clear();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Ahmm...is it okay if I do it like this `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", row["product_name"]);`??

Comment: Yes, but you need to convert to the appropriate datatype, also look at the updated answer to get an idea on a change that will avoid to recreate the parameters at each loop

Comment: Okay, I tried to add the reference `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` but I can't find it in the list. Where I can find it?

Comment: Which Version of DotNet Framework are you using? However, right click on the References of your project and select Add Reference, click on Assembly and search for System.Data.DataSetExtensions. Then double click the file and confirm the dialog box

Comment: I tried to run the application even without adding the reference you have said. It returns an error saying `Specified cast is not valid`?? Do you think that is the cause?

Comment: The Type between the minor/mayor symbol must be the same datatype of the columns in your table. Otherwise you get this error. Check the datatype of the columns and change the <xxxx> accordingly. For the reference problem, if you are able to compile then the reference is already there.

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.. That's what I did I click the assemblies and then on the extensions I search for `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` what I found is `System.Data.SqlServerCe`.

Comment: Search in the Framework sublist not in the Extension sublist. Or use the Textbox on the upper left corner

Comment: Okay I think it is already included because there is already a check in the checkbox. The problem now is the error `Specified cast is not valid`. I'll check on it later. Thanks!

Comment: Sir I have a question. Is it okay that I have a datatype of varchar of a column in my database while I declare it as a string in the code of my program?

Comment: Yes, I cannot find an authoritative sourse on this, but varchar columns should be read as string variables. http://www.functionx.com/mysqlnet/vcnet/Lesson06.htm

Comment: Okay..I think this is where the problem is I have a column `size` and `quantity` which is on type `tinyint` and `mediumint`, respectively. I tried to comment this two in the code and it does not throw errors when compiled/run. So what do you think is the problem with this two column in my database?

Comment: tinyint is just one byte so passing an integer is probably wrong. Also mediumint is three byte and also in this case is a bit off. If it is possible I would try to change the columns to INT.

Comment: I already change the columns type to INT, run the application but getting the same error. In addition, in my parameters I declared it as an INT.  Why do you think is that?

Comment: But your in memory DataTable (from where we cast the values to <int> or <string> has a compatible datatype in the corresponding column? I mean, if I try to read from the field "size" an integer I need to be sure that column is effectively an integer. Can you check this please?